# Using AOP to track code usage patterns in a Java Application

Tags: java, aop, usage-statistics

I am curious if anyone out there has used AOP to track code usage patterns in a Java Application? My goal is to log to the database all the java classes and methods that are being called with the goal of identifying unused code. Any pointers in the right direction will help as well. My Java application is not spring enabled.  Thanks!

Comment: usually done in the testing environment, but look at clover, cobertura, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For the particular purpose you mention of identifying unused code, you may want to take a look at [Unnecessary Code Detector](http://www.ucdetector.org/). Note however that it requires Eclipse.

Comment: I believe the above eclipse plugin is for finding static references and not for code invoked dynamically through reflection.